# Push Notification Not Pushing

Tags: acumatica

Version 22.103  I've defined a built-in definition class per the help -> https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d903e5af-1446-4b74-b492-087e8110cdf0

I'm trying to send PO information when a user updates any field.  I can see my class in the Push Notifications screen but, nothing is being pushed when I update a PO.  Not sure why?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.PushNotifications.Sources;
using PX.PushNotifications.UI.DAC;
using PX.Objects.PO;

public class MyPONotification : IInCodeNotificationDefinition
{
    public Tuple<BqlCommand, PXDataValue[]> GetSourceSelect()
    {
        return
         Tuple.Create(
        PXSelectJoin<POOrder,
        InnerJoin<POLine,
          On<POLine.orderNoteID, Equal<POOrder.noteID>>>>.GetCommand(),
        new PXDataValue[0]);

    //return
    //  Tuple.Create(
    //    PXSelectJoin<PushNotificationsHook,
    //    LeftJoin<PushNotificationsSource,
    //      On<PushNotificationsHook.hookId,
    //        Equal<PushNotificationsSource.hookId>>>>
    //    .GetCommand(), new PXDataValue[0]);
    }

    public Type[] GetRestrictedFields()
    {
    return null;
    
    //return new[]
    //{
    //    typeof(PushNotificationsHook.address),
    //    typeof(PushNotificationsHook.type),
    //    typeof(PushNotificationsSource.designID),
    //    typeof(PushNotificationsSource.inCodeClass),
    //    typeof(PushNotificationsSource.lineNbr)
    //};
    }
}
```

[image: Push Notification Setup]

[image]

TIA!

Comment: What does the warning next to the "Track All Fields" say?

Comment: I updated the original to include a screenshot of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a defect in 22.103.  I tried the same code/dll in 22.111 and it worked without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is in the Inner Join statement

```
InnerJoin<POLine,
    On<POLine.orderNoteID, Equal<POOrder.noteID>>
```

I recommend always to write the joins of the Header-Details/Parent-Child tables by using the keys like below:

```
InnerJoin<POLine,
    On<POLine.orderType, Equal<POOrder.orderType>,
        And<POLine.orderNbr,Equal<POOrder.orderNbr>>>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that initially but moved to the noteID when that didn't work.  I just tried again to make sure - still not getting any pushes when I update a PO - cancel a line, change status from Open to Hold and Hold to Open, etc.